# When two words are put together as in "put down" - is it a phrase?

Tags: phrases

When two words are put together as in "heads up", "put down", "build out"... are they considered a phrase? And if so, do the term for these are "adjectival phrases" as they mention on this question: [Is "put together" an adjectival phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64654/is-put-together-an-adjectival-phrase).

Comment: I assume the "phrase" used in context is something akin to, "She was very 'put together'."

Comment: They aren’t all the same, and what you call them depends on what they’re doing. All those you mention, except 'put together', can be both nouns and phrasal verbs. It might help if you could refine your question a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the basic question of whether the words constitute a phrase, the answer is a **Yes**.

Whether the pair of words constitutes a phrasal verb, an attributive phrase or another depends on the particular words and their implication.

Also, when the words so together serve to convey a certain definite sense, different from the meanings of the individual words, and this sense is accepted over time, they are generally called a 'set phrase'.

Further to this, I feel your post has too many questions in one and is ambiguous.